# Deriving derivatives with differentials

Tags: derivatives

What does it mean to derive the rule $d(x^3)=3x^2dx$ using differentials? Are differentials derivatives? In that case what is the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some pedagogical tools for describing derivatives which date back to the presentation given by Leibniz and which form the foundation of Non-Standard Analysis.

These techniques differ from the standard epsilon delta approach to derivatives and can be formalized by a set of algebraic type rules.

H. Jerome Keisler, David Tall, and some other educators maintain that the use of infinitesimals is more intuitive and more easily grasped by students than the "epsilon–delta" approach to analytic concepts.

As a result in some early calculus courses they introduce a subset of these techniques as a pedagogical tool and they are presented as allowed shortcuts which can be used when taking derivatives.

I recommend checking your notes or book to see what is allowed.

I will take a guess based on what I have seen before:

$\frac{d(x^{3})}{dx} = 3x^{2}$, so $d(x^{3}) = 3x^{2}dx$.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your background is. But the term *differential* often refers to the differential operator $d$ in the so called de Rham complex

$$0 \to \Omega^0(\mathbb{R}) \xrightarrow{d} \Omega^1(\mathbb{R}) \xrightarrow{d} \cdots$$

where $\Omega^k(\mathbb{R})$ is the space of (differential) $k$-forms. In degree $0$, the space $\Omega^0(\mathbb{R})$ is simply the space of smooth (infinitely differentiable) real valued functions.

Therefore, given the smooth function $x^3 \in \Omega^0(\mathbb{R})$, its differential is the $1$-form $d(x^3) \in \Omega^1(\mathbb{R})$ given by $$d(x^3) = 3x^2dx.$$

$1$-forms are simply the usual differential of differentiable functions we are already familiar with.

Does this help you?

Comment: I think that you lost Burt at "de Rham complex" and the following chain.

Answer (score 0):

There's a variety of ways to derive differential rules.  I'm not sure exactly what you are looking for, but a fairly straightforward way is to find the difference between a function at $x = x$ and $x = x + dx$, and simplify using certain rules.

So, for instance,
$$
d(x^3) = (x + dx)^3 - (x)^3 \\
d(x^3) = x^3 + 3x^2\, dx + 3x\,dx^2 + dx^3 - x^3 \\
d(x^3) = 3x^2\, dx + 3x\,dx^2 + dx^3 \\
d(x^3) \simeq 3x^2\,dx
$$

To understand the last simplification you can think of  multiplying decimals.  If I multiply $0.001$ by $0.001$, the result will be even smaller, $0.000001$.  If you think about a differential as essentially having an infinite number of zeroes after the decimal, multiplying two differentials together gives a value that is essentially infinitely tinier than either differential alone.  Therefore, they are essentially ignorable.

A *derivative* is simply a taking a differential of both sides of an equation and solving for some ratio of differentials.

I'm basing the process here on the *Calculus Made Easy* method.  However, if that's the book you are using, it is normally done by simply replacing every instance of $x$ with $dx$, $y$ with $dy$, etc.  So, you would transform the equation:

$$ y = x^3 $$
into
$$ (y + dy) = (x + dx)^3  \\
y + dy = x^3 + 3x^2\, dx + 3x\,dx^2 + dx^3 \\
dy = 3x^2\, dx + 3x\,dx^2 + dx^3 \\
dy \simeq 3x^2\, dx \\
\frac{dy}{dx} \simeq 3x^2
$$
The step between line 2 and line 3 is because, since $y = x^3$, we can subtract $y$ from the left and $x^3$ on the right and it will be the same thing.